# Sorting a multilevel index

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to understand how to sort a multiindexed series or dataframe within a level.

Example:

Actual output:

```
Sheep  Bats
black  No      0.750000
       Yes     0.250000
white  No      0.857143
       Yes     0.142857
dtype: float64
```

Desired output (sorted within Bats, level=1):

```
Sheep  Bats
black  Yes     0.250000
       No      0.750000
white  Yes     0.142857
       No      0.857143
    
dtype: float64
```

I've tried calling MultiIndex.sortlevel() (see below for how to reproduce my work) but it doesn't seem to be working for me, and I also don't see labels within my MultiIndex.

This is my code and sample data.

```
Sheep,Bats,Cats,Dogs
white,No,Yes,No
white,No,Yes,Yes
black,Yes,Yes,Yes
black,No,Yes,No
white,No,No,No
white,No,Yes,No
white,No,Yes,Yes
white,Yes,Yes,Yes
black,No,Yes,Yes
black,No,Yes,No
white,No,No,Yes
```

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df = df.set_index(["Sheep","Bats"])
df.index.sortlevel(level=1, ascending=False) # what I've tried
s = pd.Series(df.groupby(["Sheep","Bats"]).size(), index=df.index)
n = s.groupby(["Sheep","Bats"]).size()
d =  s.groupby(["Sheep"]).size()
p = n/d
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a list with booleans to the `ascending` parameter of `.sort_index`:

```
df.sort_index(ascending=[True, False])


           Cats Dogs
Sheep Bats          
black Yes   Yes  Yes
      No    Yes   No
      No    Yes  Yes
      No    Yes   No
white Yes   Yes  Yes
      No    Yes   No
      No    Yes  Yes
      No     No   No
      No    Yes   No
      No    Yes  Yes
      No     No  Yes
```